# ERROR in node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/action-sheet/action-sheet-component.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic with angular. today morning i tried to update angular and and got errors. During fix these errors got more errors. At least I delete package-lock.json and node_module folder and install again an run project. I also run that command to update dependecies `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force`. I got this error this time. Please anyone help.

```
ERROR in node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/action-sheet/action-sheet-component.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has n
o exported member 'Renderer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/alert/alert-component.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Rend
erer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d.ts:1:72 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Di
d you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ElementRef, InjectionToken, OnInit, Renderer, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                          ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'.
 Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts:1:70 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Rendere
r'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ElementRef, ErrorHandler, NgZone, Renderer, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/backdrop/backdrop.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer
'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/badge/badge.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Did
 you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/button/button.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. D
id you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/card/card-content.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer
'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
[ng] node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/card/card-header.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'
. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
```

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "assignment-2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "latest",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.9",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-stripe": "^1.5.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": ">= 5.5.7 <8",
    "ionic-angular": "latest",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.7.5",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.6",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.9",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.12.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.3.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-stripe": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "929354685211"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I search this issue on google but does not found any solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Having to use `--allow-dirty --force` should have given you enough warning to avoid the situation you are in right now. Angular CLI and NPM have a few mechanisms aim to ensure version compatibility.

For future I suggest using the angular update utility [https://update.angular.io] which will guide you through updating angular and its dependencies while ensuring best practices.

For your current situation the only thing I can recommend is starting with a fresh `package.json` and manually installing all the components you need using either `ng add` or `npm install`. Or go back to the last working commit in your version history and then update properly from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with the angular version, "ionic-angular" is used with angular versions up to 5. If we want to use a later angular version with ionic then we have to use "@ionic/angular". Following link help me to solve the problem.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-build-an-ionic-angular-app-after-packages-upgrade/197497